# Music library MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need some help building a table(s) for a music database in MySQL. I am unsure on how to lay this information out in a table.

Here is the info I would like to be stored in the database.

```
Artist Name
Album Name
Release Date
Genre
Picture URL (album artwork)

Track Number
Trank Name
Track Playtime
Lyric (optional, But would like to have it someday)

etc.
```

Basically anything that has to do with organizing digital music. I'm new to databases and I have some ideas. But if I'm going to learn I might as well learn the right way of doing it.

Any thoughts on how to design my table(s) would be awesome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this would be good to start with.  It specifies a table for artists, albums (with keys into artists and genres), tracks (keyed into albums), and genres.

```
Table artists
----
id (primary key),
name
description
years_active
otherinfo (whatever you need)

Table albums
----
id (primary key)
artistid (foreign key to artists table)
name,
releasedate
genreid (foreign key to genres table)
picture

Table tracks
----
id (primary key)
albumid (foreign key to albums table)
name
override_artist (overrides album artist if not null)
playtime
lyric
otherstuff as needed

Table genres
----
id (primary key)
name
description
```

Comment: This assumes all tracks on an album share an artist, which is not always the case.

Comment: Awesome, that was the answer I was looking for. I'm new to programming with php and mysql. So, learn how to build a table the right way first is a great start. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following database structure:

```
artist { id, name }
genre { id, name }
album { id, name, artist_id, release_date, genre_id, picture_url }
track { id, album_id, number, name, playtime, lyrics }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Artist ( ArtistID INT PRIMARY KEY, ArtistName )
Genre ( GenreID TINYINT PRIMARY KEY, GenreDescription )
Album ( AlbumID INT PRIMARY KEY, ArtistID INT, GenreID INT ReleaseDate )
AlbumArt ( AlbumArtID INT PRIMARY KEY, AlbumID INT, AlbumArtPath )
Track ( AlbumID INT, TrackNumber INT, TrackName, PlayTime, Lyrics , PRIMARY KEY ( AlbumID, TrackNumber ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The database schematic is about laying out the tables and establishing the relationships between those tables.

You have already identified many table candidates: Track, Artist, Album

Then you need the relationships: Artist can have many albums, album can have many tracks.

With these few simple tables and relationships in place you already have a small database.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.freedb.org/en/. Formerly cddb.org, it's a free music database. You can download the whole database from one of their links and see how they've done it.

Comment: Awesome stuff. I had the chance to look over this on my weekend, I had one problem, I looked like CDs with 10,11,12 plus tracks it did not record them. So, in a CD that has 20 tracks it stopped at 11ish. See what I'm saying. Maybe I was doing something wrong. But thanks for the reply, I might use this in my programs down the road. I'm building a database for my music collection and comparing it to my wants.