# Problems normalizing and inserting data into Oracle music database

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

I'm working on a school project for a beginner SQL course where I've uploaded a portion of my music library's metadata into Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE  "MUSIC" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "ARTIST" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "ALBUM" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "TRACK" NUMBER, 
    "YEAR" NUMBER, 
    "GENRE" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "NAMEID" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "MUSIC_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "bi_MUSIC" 
  before insert on "MUSIC"              
  for each row 
begin  
  if :new."ID" is null then
    select "MUSIC_SEQ".nextval into :new."ID" from sys.dual;
  end if;
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "bi_MUSIC" ENABLE
/

CREATE TABLE  "ALBUMS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "ARTISTID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "RELEASEDATE" NUMBER, 
    "GENREID" NUMBER, 
    "GENRENAME" VARCHAR2(255), 
     CONSTRAINT "ALBUMS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "ALBUMS" ADD CONSTRAINT "ALBUMS_CON2" FOREIGN KEY ("ARTISTID")
      REFERENCES  "ARTIST" ("ID") ENABLE
/
ALTER TABLE  "ALBUMS" ADD CONSTRAINT "ALBUMS_CON3" FOREIGN KEY ("GENREID")
      REFERENCES  "GENRES" ("ID") ENABLE
/
CREATE TABLE  "ARTIST" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255), 
     CONSTRAINT "ARTIST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/
CREATE TABLE  "GENRES" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255), 
     CONSTRAINT "GENRES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/
CREATE TABLE  "TRACKS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "ALBUMID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "NUMBER" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "TRACKS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "TRACKS" ADD CONSTRAINT "TRACKS_CON3" FOREIGN KEY ("ALBUMID")
      REFERENCES  "ALBUMS" ("ID") ENABLE
/
```

The MUSIC table is not part of the actual hierarchy, it's only there to allow me to upload data into the database and then insert it into the ALBUMS, ARTIST, GENRES, and TRACKS tables. I've assigned primary and foreign keys between those 4 tables as described in the top answer for this question, and trimmed columns I don't have:
[Music library MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234182/music-library-mysql-database)

I've successfully inserted some of the data already, but now I've run into issues with inserting data into the GENRENAME and GENREID columns in the ALBUMS table. Inserting the following:

```
insert into albums (genrename, genreid)
select name, id
from genres
```

yields the following error message:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TIMOILONEN"."ALBUMS"."ID")`

I've already got two columns (ID and ARTISTID) with the identical values in this table which I am not even sure is permitted.

In addition, trying to insert missing data into the TRACKS table yields errors:

```
insert into tracks (name, number)
select title, track
from music`
```

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column
>   specification

Both the NAME and TITLE columns have data type `VARCHAR2(255)` while the NUMBER and TRACK columns have data type `NUMBER`.
I also have the ID and ALBUMID columns with identical data in this table, like in the ALBUMS table.

I greatly appreciate anyone willing to help me with filling the missing data and properly normalizing the tables. I was already due to present this earlier this week, but had to postpone my presentation to this coming Friday due to these problems.

--

Following advise given to me below, I created triggers for the ALBUMS and TRACKS tables for inserting values into the ID columns, copying the commands from the MUSIC table where inserting ID works correctly. However, I am still unsure as to what kind of command I am supposed to use to activate the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "bi_TRACKS" 
  before insert on "TRACKS"              
  for each row 
begin  
  if :new."ID" is null then
    select "MUSIC_SEQ".nextval into :new."ID" from sys.dual;
  end if;
end;

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "bi_TRACKS" ENABLE
/   

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "bi_ALBUMS" 
  before insert on "ALBUMS"              
  for each row 
begin  
  if :new."ID" is null then
    select "MUSIC_SEQ".nextval into :new."ID" from sys.dual;
  end if;
end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "bi_ALBUMS" ENABLE
/


insert into albums (genreid, genrename, id)
select id, name, 'NULL'
from genres
```

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Please read [ask].  Do not post links to external images.  Put your table definitions in a text.  Thanks.

Comment: Insert into does not use column lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inserting the following:
>
> ```
> insert into albums (genrename, genreid)
> select name, id
> from genres
> ```
>
> yields the following error message:
>
> > ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TIMOILONEN"."ALBUMS"."ID")`

This is because the `ID` column in `ALBUMS` is not allowed to have `NULL` values in it.

When creating a table, you can specify any column in a table to be `NOT NULL`.  Oracle will then stop you from inserting `NULL` values into that column. However, if a column is the primary key (or part of the primary key) it will automatically be made `NOT NULL`.  This has happened to the `ID` column of `ALBUMS`.

If you want to insert an album into `ALBUMS`, you must give the database the ID of the album to create.  You could specify values for these IDs into the `INSERT` statement you use to put data into these tables.  Alternatively, you could use a sequence and a trigger to insert values into the `ID` column, as you are doing with the `MUSIC` table.  If you're using Oracle 12c you could also use identity columns.

> In addition, trying to insert missing data into the TRACKS table
>   yields errors:
>
> ```
> insert into tracks (name, number)
> select title, track
> from music
> ```
>
> > ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column
> >     specification

This is a more unfortunate problem.  Oracle here is objecting to a column named `number`, because there is also a datatype named `NUMBER` and it can't tell the difference.  (With any database you are likely to run into problems if you have a column name the same as a keyword that the database recognises.)  You can get round this by either renaming the column to `TRACK_NUMBER`, say, or by putting the column name in double-quotes:

```
insert into tracks (name, "NUMBER")
select title, track
from music
```

Either way, note however that you are then likely to see the error

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("TIMOILONEN"."TRACKS"."ID")

This however is just the first problem again.  The `ID` column in `TRACKS` needs a value and you are not giving it anything.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the informative post. I tried creating triggers for inserting values into ID for both the ALBUMS and TRACKS tables but ran into issues. I updated the original post, please take a look at it.

Comment: @TimoIlonen: the "invalid number" error you're getting is because you are trying to insert a string value with the text "NULL" into a column that takes numbers.  (A string containing the text `NULL` is not the same as the `NULL` value.) Leave the `id` column out of the `INSERT` statement, i.e. `insert into albums (genreid, genrename) select id, name from genres`, and then the trigger should fire.