# How to model a MySQL table containing records of an ordered list?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Referring to this post: [Music library MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234182/music-library-mysql-database)

```
artist { id, name }
genre { id, name }
album { id, name, artist_id, release_date, genre_id, picture_url }
track { id, album_id, number, name, playtime, lyrics }
```

Using the above table structure, how does one prevent an insert of two tracks with the same track number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make

```
ALTER TABLE track 
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_track UNIQUE (album_id, number);
```

The unique key  would prevent with an error to enter for the same album_id two tracks with the same number.

Comment: Yep, that's what `UNIQUE` constraints are for.